# Where can I find a complete list of available locale texts of ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Looking into [ag-grid documentations](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-internationalisation/) won't give me a useful information about how to find all available locale texts.

There are some missing texts like `notEqual` or `notContains` which I could guess them, but can't find how to translate `and` and `or` condition in filters. No guides, nobody mentioned it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localeText` is where you define. https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/javascript-grid-internationalisation/internationalisation/main.js

and `localeTextFunc` is where you return via default.

so you can have `default.locale.js`

```
// all keys
module.export = {
    page: 'page',
    ... 
};
```

when you set gridOptions, you can do:

```
import localeText from './default.locale';
import localeFrench from './locale.fr';

{
  localeText,
  localeTextFunc: (key, defaultValue) => localeFrench[key] || defaultValue
}
```

Obviously you can make this a locales `Map` and have the key of the current one being searched - but there does not seem to be any pre-defined locales available in their repo.

This is not really a reactjs question so removing tag.